# Beginner Reactjs question if there is no "main" in the package.json how does React know what file to start in

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, package.json

Beginner Reactjs question.
If there is no "main" in the package.json how does create-react-app know what file to start in?
I see the `"root"` in index.html, does React search trough all files looking for the `ReactDom`? to plug it in under the root?

Comment: That's outside the scope of react, it doesn't contain any code loader by default, are you referring to create-react-app ?

Comment: In index.html there should be multiple entry points to different files.

Comment: However some tools are configured to rename the entry point to whatever value passed from package.json

Comment: Yea I make a create-react-app and asking questions about it.

Answer (score 0):

Its because the node server (which CRA runs on) doesnt need guidance.
its default behaviour is to run at the project directory and find file named "index"